# Create a virtual multitouch device using uinput driver

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, linux-device-driver

I'm try to inject event on an android device without touchscreen. I'm using user space input device (uinput) to do so but it doesn't work.

I'm using this code:

```
fd_virtual_dev = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd_virtual_dev < 0)
    return die("error: open");

if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_ABS) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ev_abs");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_SYN) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ev_syn");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_TOUCH_M AJOR) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_WIDTH_M AJOR) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_POSITIO N_X) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ABS_MT_POSITION_X");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_POSITIO N_Y) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ABS_MT_POSITION_Y");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_TRACKIN G_ID) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_SLOT) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl");
if (ioctl(fd_virtual_dev,UI_SET_ABSBIT,ABS_MT_PRESSUR E) < 0)
    return die("error: ioctl ABS_MT_PRESSURE");

memset(&uidev, 0, sizeof(uidev));
snprintf(uidev.name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE, "uinput-device");
uidev.id.bustype = BUS_VIRTUAL;
uidev.id.vendor = 0x0;
uidev.id.product = 0x0;
uidev.id.version = 0;    
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR] = 64;
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_WIDTH_MAJOR] = 64;
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_POSITION_X] = 1024;
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_POSITION_Y] = 800;
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID] = 65535;
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_SLOT] = 9;
uidev.absmax[ABS_MT_PRESSURE] = 64;
```

Now, if I try to sende multitouch protocolo B events I can see only a little circle on the screen in an pseduorandom point

I'v tried also with protocoll A and on a touchscreen phone with the same result
Alfonso

Comment: Have you solve your problem?
I am also looking for a way to create multitouch devices use uinput as yours,but I can't even create a single touch.
so I want get some help from you.

Comment: No! I could not find any valid solutions

Answer (score 2):

If UI_SET_PROPBIT is NOT defined in the header file 'uinput.h' you are including, add below line:

```
#define UI_SET_PROPBIT    _IOW(UINPUT_IOCTL_BASE, 110, int)
```

before the line:

```
ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_SET_PROPBIT, INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
```

I tested it on Nexus7. The touch event works well except it cannot apply on the Android system virtual buttons (BACK, HOME and RECENT) which is a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following ioctl call:

```
ioctl(dev_file, UI_SET_PROPBIT, INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to add an IDC file (as described [here](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html)) for the product and vendor IDs you've specified, under `/system/usr/idc`. In your case it would be `/system/usr/idc/Vendor_0000_Product_0000.idc`, though consider using unique product/vendor values.

The IDC file should specify that the device is a touch screen:
`touch.deviceType = touchScreen`

Without an IDC file, the device is likely being identified as a mouse, which results in the little circle. If you're building a custom Android image, you can drop the IDC file in the Android source tree under `/out/target/product/<product>/system/usr/idc`. Otherwise try uploading the IDC via "adb shell".